# POST request - 406 Security Incident Detected

Tags: security, curl, post, node-red, http-status-code-406

I'm trying to fetch a schedule from a URL by submitting the form values in a POST request. For this purpose, I created a flow in node-red and it worked fine for few weeks. However, now I've started to receive the following security error.

> 406 Security Incident Detected
>
> ## 406 Security Incident Detected
>
> Your request was blocked. Please try again later.
>
> ---
>
> XrxWwwzlK-WmpFeEbGejEwAAAEo - www.islamiskaforbundet.se - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Interesting thing is, when I put the parameters in a REST development tool (such as **Postman** or **Open RESTED**) and post the request, I get the data without any issues.

Below is the CURL request generated from Postman:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://www.islamiskaforbundet.se/wp-content/plugins/bonetider/Bonetider_Widget.php \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'postman-token: eb701a0e-406e-4851-653f-2b7818c7d455' \
  -d 'ifis_bonetider_widget_city=G%C3%B6teborg%2C%20SE&ifis_bonetider_widget_date=2020-05-14'
```

Upon execution, it fails in terminal.

One could say that the server may have learned my IP address and started to block all incoming requests, but then why the same request would work fine in the above mentioned tools' UI but not in CURL or my node-red flow?

Is there anything I'm missing? or how to avoid this security error?

Comment: This will be extremely tough to answer without more knowledge on how that server specifically is implementing its security measures. At first glance, it seems like some sort of middleware that the server is using to fingerprint different clients and it seems to have identified your client/code as a security risk (possibly because you're making requests too fast or other behaviors not aligning with typical user activity), and blocked that fingerprint from making requests.

Comment: But then why the requests made through Postman are successful and not the one through my script? and how can a server identify which client is sending the request within a private network other than knowing the public IP address of my router? Is there a way that I can randomize the client identity through headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server at the other end has a number of ways to identify the which client is making the request, but the most likely one is that it is looking at the [User Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) string from the client making the request.

e.g. you can make the curl command work by adding the Firefox User Agent header:

```
curl -X POST   https://www.islamiskaforbundet.se/wp-content/plugins/bonetider/Bonetider_Widget.php  \
-A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0" \
-H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
-H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
-d 'ifis_bonetider_widget_city=G%C3%B6teborg%2C%20SE&ifis_bonetider_widget_date=2020-05-14'
```

(I also removed the postman token)

Also [406](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406) is probably the wrong error for the server to be returning, a better match for the text of the error would be something like [429](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429)

Comment: Setting the User-Agent in the header did the trick. Thanks :)
What still puzzles me is that I don't manually set user-agent in Postman's UI but it still works... perhaps the tool automatically sets it in the request?